# Jquery/Ajax file uploader

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, file, upload

Im looking for a jquery or ajax file uploader, Im currently using the FancyUploader which worked great until Flash brought out their update making all flash progress bars absolete, now whenever I try to upload large files... it will fill the progress bar to 100% in a matter of seconds even though the actual upload finished minutes after. So im now looking for a new uploading script that DOESNT require flash but can still display the progress.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[UploadProgress](http://nixboxdesigns.com/demos/jquery-uploadprogress.php) (requires jQuery and PHP, but not Flash) looks like it may do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.swfupload.org/ works fine with recent versions of Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try my beta ajax mutiple upload jquery based, simple efficient download it at: http://www.albanx.com/  . no flash, with progress, work over https, support main browsers..

Answer (score 0):

At this point i'd stay away from flash plugins. I'd use HTML5 uploader instead like this one:valums uploader

Sure - you'll be able to select multiple files in modern browsers only, otherwise - it'll be file by file. but hey - if person doesn't care about upgrading to newer browsers - they really probably don't know how to Ctrl+click anyways.

Flash doesn't send cookies correctly (it sends IE cookies even if you use firefox or google chrome). So - you'll lose cookies and thus sessions. There is a workaround - to send PHPSESSID in POST requests - but it simply opens door wide open for session fixation.